# How to Upload Bitmap images through retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2, image-uploading, capture

Captured image is in BITMAP format. Generally we do compress the image before uploading it to server. I need to upload the image without compressing. Please find the code below:

```
if (CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST == 11) 
{
    switch (resultCode)
    {
        case CertificationAddOwnerImage.RESULT_OK:
            if(CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST==11)
            {
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                click_img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                //onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "The file was saved at"+imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i doubt you hardly searched once before asking...

Comment: `Captured image is in BITMAP format. `. No it certainly is a jpg file.

Comment: `Generally we do compress the image before uploading it to server. I need to upload the image without compressing. `. You are creating problems yourself. You should just upload that jpg file.

Answer (score 3):

what you can try is to get byte array of bitmap

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

then upload byte array through request body

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody
        .create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), byteArray);
```